# Will deployment of web application that is under main site in IIS cause take down of the main site?

Tags: iis, web-applications, application-pool

I have main website hosted in my IIS and under that I have multiple applications (another web apps) that run on a separate application pool. I know that if you will change some files of site that is hosted in IIS it will result into application pool recycling. However I am not sure what will happen in my scenario, from one hand they have different app pools, but from another hand application is hosted under main website.

Is it possible to deploy application that is hosted under web site without disrupting main site operation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it wont. If you have your main site and applications running under different application pool, you should be fine.

Application Domains and application pool ensure isolation with respect to applications on IIS. Changes made to application will cause specific application domain to refresh and will not have an impact on other applications.